# C#, .net 4.5 and angularjs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angularjs

I am very new to the angularjs. I just started learning. I created simple aspx page but it is not working as expected but if I make same in html page it works. 
Thing is that when click button counter should increase but it don't work in aspx page but works in html page

So can somebody tell me what be the reason

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Angular.Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="" ng-init="hour=13">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-click="count = count + 1">Click me!</button>
  <p>{{ count }}</p>
</div>
<script>
  function myController($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
  }
</script>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what "doesn't work"?

Comment: I edit the question. Kindly check it

Comment: i have tried, it is working for me.

Comment: Are sure it is working in webform. I am using .Net 4.5

Comment: Hold on, posted answer, i was using `brackets` an IDE to check JS, it was working there, but not in IIS or asp.net website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

`<input type="button" ng-click="count = count + 1" value="Click me!" />`

instead of

`<button ng-click="count = count + 1">Click me!</button>`

Comment: <button> might be submitting the form, whereas <input type=button.. , is not doing that. You can see that earlier solution, just refresh the page- means submitting the page/form. More info - http://web.archive.org/web/20110721191046/http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/

Comment: @John , definitely you can develop SPA using ASP.Net/Server side technology, but you have to be careful while do so, like take care of `runat=server` , that might manipulate control id, there can be many careful steps need to be taken. But do you see, difference , between my and your suggestion. Or are you still confused? Let me know, so that i can explain it in better words.

Comment: @ArindamNayak oh I get it, I was trying to help him with future headaches and help him understand the underlying issue, not just a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

it would be better if you define an app name in angular

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-init="hour=13">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-click="click()">Click me!</button>
  <p>{{ count }}</p>
</div>
<script>
  angular.module('myapp').controller('myController', ['$scope',
      function myController($scope) {
        $scope.count = 0;
        $scope.click = function(){
           $scope.count++;
        };
      }
  ]);
</script>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```